# Analysing weird function behaviour

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using numerical methods, i got that function $u(x)$, defined by the first order ODE $du/dx=\pi cos(\pi x)+p(u-sin(\pi x))^4$,where $p$ is a real-valued parameter, doesn't change almost at all with variation of parameter p, at least on the interval from 0 to 1.  Namely, $u(0)=u(1)=0$, $u(0.5)=1$ and $u(x)$'s graph looks like that of $sin(\pi x)$. I was wondering why this behaviour holds independently of $p$. Couldn't prove or understand it, maybe someone can give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the ODE you will observe that for suitable initial condition, $u(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ is an analytic solution. The nonlinear $p$-term is vanishing in this case.

The reason you will most likely see small differences if you solve numerically is, that your algorithm will be a little off compared to the exact solution. So the $p$-term will actually be nonzero and the value of $p$ will play a role.

Edit: things will change really fast if you don't start with $u(0)=0$. Then you will see the solution changing drastically if you alter the value of $p$.

Comment: You made a small typo: replace $1$ by $u(x)$ in the last term. For a full solution for all initial values, see the other solution.

Comment: yes! im really sorry, just noticed the typo, wanted to delete it, and then noticed oyu already replied. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Set $v(x)=u(x)-\sin(\pi x)$, then 
$$
v'(x)=pv(x)^4\implies v(x)^{-3}-v(0)^{-3}=-3px
\implies v(x)=\frac{v(0)}{\sqrt[3]{1-3pv(0)^3x}}
$$
This has a singularity at $x=\frac1{3pv(0)^3}$, if that falls inside the interval $[0,1]$, you get some explosive behavior that does not play nice with numerical methods.

However, your initial value is $v(0)=0$ and thus $v(x)=0$ for all $x$. The numerical errors can be interpreted into an exact solution with a very small initial value $v(0)$. Thus $u(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ up to very small perturbations that are not visible in a plot.